# Prevent kf.dbusaddons: DBus session bus not found. To circumvent this try the following command (with bash): export $(dbus-launch)

Tags: ubuntu, kde, kde-plasma-5, dbus, kde-plasma-workspace

To launch GUI applications in kde (plasma) in Ubuntu Jammy I need to first manually do `export $(dbus-launch)` and then launch the app from this console

Otherwise it won't start (saying `kf.dbusaddons: DBus session bus not found. To circumvent this problem try the following command (with bash):     export $(dbus-launch)` )

Circumventing is not the intention, the intention is to prevent once and for all. How do I achieve this?

Removing and then installing afresh kde, plasma, dbus didn't help